# New line break overlaps previous text css

Tags: css, html

I have this div that contains text. However, when it creates a new line, it overlaps the top text. I am using a font called pageant. However, even if I use a default HTMLfont, the problem still exists.

Here's the code of the DIV:

`<div id="scoresDiv" class="scoresDiv" style="text-align:center;width:400px;height:inherit;overflow:hidden;background-color:transparent;color:white;">`

`<div style="margin-top:200px;font-size:90px;font-family:pageant;background-color:transparent;display: inline-block;">Hello Stackoverflow</div></div>`

Here's an image of the problem.[image]

Hoping for your response. Thanks!

Comment: you should give a `line-height` property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have to give a `line-height` property, also in this case I've provided a width also.

```
<div style="margin-top:200px;font-size:90px;font-family:pageant;background-color:transparent;display: inline-block; line-height:1.4em; width:300px;">Hello Stackoverflow</div>
```

HERE is a Working **[Demo](http://jsbin.com/hagoyole/1/edit)**.

Comment: That solved it! Thank you! BTW, i used px though in my line height, 70px to be exact.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id='stackoverflow'>Hello Stackoverflow</div></div>



#stackoverflow{
margin-top:200px;
font-size:90px;
font-family:pageant;
background-color:transparent;
display: inline-block;
line-height:50px;
}
```